# MySQL Parameter must be defined with C#

Tags: c#, mysql, parameters

I created a stored procedure on a MySQL database and it works fine if i run it directly from Navicat (a SGBD) but if i try to run the script of the stored procedure from C# code i get an error "Parameter '@req' must be defined". My code bellow:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS SP_GET_EXPERIENCE_RECORD_STATISTICS;

CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GET_EXPERIENCE_RECORD_STATISTICS(IN startTime  VARCHAR(19), IN endTime VARCHAR(19), IN isEquipment INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE req VARCHAR(1000);
SET @req = "SELECT ";

IF(isEquipment = 1) THEN
    SET @req = CONCAT(@req, "ClientName,");
ELSE
    SET @req = CONCAT(@req, "ContentName 'ClientName',");
END IF;

SET req = CONCAT(req, " COUNT(1) 'ConsumeCount',
SUM(Points) 'PointsCount',
SUM(CASE WHEN Mode = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'CardCount',
SUM(CASE WHEN Mode = 1 THEN Points ELSE 0 END) 'CardPoints',
SUM(CASE WHEN Mode = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 'WeChatCount',
SUM(CASE WHEN Mode = 0 THEN Points ELSE 0 END) 'WeChatPoints'
FROM experiencerecord
WHERE EndTime BETWEEN '", startTime, "' AND '", endTime, "'");

IF (isEquipment = 1) THEN
    SET @req = CONCAT(@req, " GROUP BY ClientName");
ELSE
    SET req = CONCAT(req, " GROUP BY ContentName");
END IF;

PREPARE stmt FROM @req;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END;

 -- CALL SP_GET_EXPERIENCE_RECORD_STATISTICS('2010-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-12-31 23:59:59', 0);
 -- CALL SP_GET_EXPERIENCE_RECORD_STATISTICS('2010-01-01 00:00:00', '2016-12-31 23:59:59', 1);
```

And my code in C# :

```
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DatabaseConnectionString);

public bool mysql(string sql)
    {
        try
        {
            MySqlCommand comm = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
            MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter(comm);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            mda.Fill(ds);
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
            throw ex;
        }

    }
```

Any idea where it come from will be very appreciated.

Comment: what is `sql` in your C# code

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Finally i added `AllowUserVariables=True;` to the connectionString and now it works super fine.

Answer (score 0):

Seems a typo error

```
IF (isEquipment = 1) THEN
    SET @req = CONCAT(@req, " GROUP BY ClientName");
ELSE
    SET @req = CONCAT(@req, " GROUP BY ContentName"); //You forgot @req here!
END IF;
```

Moreover I don't see any `AddWithParameter` line in your C# code that should be there as `@req` is a parameter.

```
MySqlDataAdapter mda = new MySqlDataAdapter(comm);
mda.Parameters.AddWithValue("@req",value_goes_here);
```

Comment: I fixed the missing @req you found so it's better but I still have an error "Parameter '@req' must be defined". That's strange, req is just a variable, not a parameter...

Comment: Try removing `@` from all `req` after `SET` keyword.